# JPQL multiple select

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpql

I want to extract all data from TypeCmplt like this :

```
    public List<TypeCmplt> listerrTypeCmplt()
throws DaoException {
    Query query = cmpltTitreEM.createQuery("select t.cdTypeCmplt, t.lbTypeCmplt from TypeCmplt t");
    List<TypeCmplt> listeType = new ArrayList<TypeCmplt>();
    listeType = query.getResultList();
    return listeType;
}
```

The test method :

```
    @Test
public void listerComplementsParTypeTest(){
    logger.debug("Afficher la liste des types de complémént") ;

    try {
        List<TypeCmplt> type = cmpltTitreDao.listerrTypeCmplt();
        for (int i = 0; i < type.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(type.get(i));
        }

    } catch (DaoException e) {
        logger.error("Erreur", e) ;
    }
```

But I get this :

```
Hibernate: select typecmplt0_.CD_TYPE_CMPLT as col_0_0_, typecmplt0_.LB_TYPE_CMPLT as col_1_0_ from TC_TYPE_CMPLT typecmplt0_
[Ljava.lang.Object;@4d2b11
[Ljava.lang.Object;@46a5c4
[Ljava.lang.Object;@2d09e0
[Ljava.lang.Object;@e38fca
```

Can anyone help, please ?

Comment: Can you please post the class `TypeCmplt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a `List<TypeCmplt>` for your results. But the result list is an array of `Object` becaus you are making a projection query - extracting single attributes of the `TypeCmplt`. If you want to get the `TypeCmplt`entities proper, change the query String to

```
"select t from TypeCmplt t"
```

If you do want to extract several attributes of the entity, but to do it in a typesafe way, then constructor expressions are the way to go:

```
List<MyClass> dtos = cmpltTitreEM.createQuery("SELECT NEW com.example.MyClass( t.cdTypeCmplt, t.lbTypeCmplt) FROM TypeCmplt t").getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but even when I tried to use slf4j to display TypeCmplt I obtained the same result, also TypeCmplt contains two columns, longs and strings, the problem is when I try to get just one column it works !

Comment: @SafwenKhalloufi - this is how projection queries work - if you are retrieving multiple attributes of your entity, you will get an array of `Object`

Comment: @SafwenKhalloufi - you're welcome. I see that my initial assumption was incorrect, so I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to print an `Object` called `TypeCmplt`. Try calling `toString()`. As @kostja said, you'd probably be better off overriding `toString()` in `TypeCmplt`.

Like this:

```
System.out.println(type.get(i).toString());
```

Or:

```
TypeCmplt t = type.get(i);
System.out.println(t.getLong() + ": " + t.getString());
```

In this case you should replace `getLong()` and `getString()` accordingly.

Comment: type contains two columns, longs and strings, the problem is when I try to get just one column it works !